# Get the data from copied filtered cells

Tags: excel, vba

If I copy some cells (simply containing numbers) from filtered column, how can I further reference this data from VBA?

If I try this:

```
Dim DataObj As MsForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MsForms.DataObject

DataObj.GetFromClipboard

Debug.Print DataObj.GetText(1)
```

I get this error:

```
DataObject:GetText Invalid FORMATETC structure
```

Is there any other way to access the data from copied filtered cells?

Comment: What you get from `GetText` is a string where values in rows are delimited by vbTab and rows are delimited by vbCrLf - if you want an array then you can write a function to turn the string into one...

Comment: That's not what I get here (Excel 2013), but error message. Are you saying that you can copy cells and then use `DataObj.GetText(1)` successfully?

Comment: I didn't mention `GetText(1)` - that doesn't work because `GetText` returns a String, not an array. If you want an array then you need to use `Split()` on the string to create an array.  Exactly how you'd do that wuold depend on how many columns you're copying an whether you want a 1-d or 2-d array.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to say. I don't have a string. `GetText` doesn't return a string - it raises error.

Comment: So if you remove the (1) from the end of that line it still errors?

Comment: Yes, haven't you tried the snippet?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you have in the clipboard so it's hard for me to test your exact exact setup, but I set up my own code and it worked fine. Maybe you can put a little more code ahead of that, to show the filter/copy steps?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
Sub Tester()

Dim DataObj As MsForms.DataObject
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, rngV As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A20") 'filtered range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngV = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rngV Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No visible cells!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'using Clipboard
    rngV.Copy
    Set DataObj = New MsForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    Debug.Print DataObj.GetText '>> vbCrLf-delimited string

    'direct read
    For Each c In rngV.Cells
        Debug.Print c.Value
    Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but the range is not known and selection is not available, as otherwise I'd use `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. I want to just access the data from clipboard, without hardcoded range, or relying on selection (which is not available at the time Sub is run).

Comment: That is not a proposal for a full solution to your problem, just some code to show that `GetText` works fine for me. I'ts not clear from your question how you're copying the cells.

Comment: I select couple of cells from filtered column, and press ctrl+c. Then I move the cursor to another cell. Now I want to run VBA code, and use the data from clipboard.

Comment: If I paste clipboard data in text editor, and select and copy the contents from text editor, I can perfectly use `DataObj.GetText`. But with clipboard contents copied from Excel sheet, I can't

Comment: I can only replicate your error if the clipboard is empty - do you by any change have VBA running on an event handler when you switch sheets or change the selection ?

Comment: No, it's fairly simple Sub working in single sheet. Can you confirm that `DataObj.GetText` works as expected on your side - i.e. you can copy some cells, move the cursor to another location, and then use my snippet to dump clipboard contents? In that case I can try to access another computer with different Excel version.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it works for me as long as there's something in the clipboard.

Comment: Just to report that I tried the snippet on another PC, but with same Excel version (2013 64 bit) and get the same error.