# Access The Nth Item of Clipboard

Tags: vba, excel, clipboard

Is there a way to retrieve several items from the clipboard? I'm using something like this:

```
Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String

Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

clipboard.GetFromClipboard
str1 = clipboard.GetText(1)
str2 = clipboard.GetText(2)
```

However, I get an error where I assign a value to my second variable that says the following:

```
  Run-time error '-2147221404 (800040064)':
  DataObject:GetText Invalid FORMATETC Structure
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is this really VBA or are you using this in VB.NET?

Comment: @MacroMan I'm doing this in Excel, so yes, I'm using VBA. Is this not possible in VBA?

Comment: I only ask because the error message doesn't look like a standard VBA error message.

Comment: Just tried the code, it does indeed produce that error message

Comment: @MacroMan I've made an update to the question showing the runtime error.

Comment: Does [this thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/77869-mydata-getfromclipboard.html) help?  or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685500/get-the-data-from-copied-filtered-cells)?

Comment: @BruceWayne Batman the problem is that it only grabs the last item pasted on the clipboard. I tried both solutions and they yield the same result.

Comment: `.GetFromClipboard` [can contain multiple data items, but each item must be in a different format. For example, the DataObject might include one text item and one item in a custom format; but cannot include two text items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278634.aspx)

Comment: Do you know if you *can* even access older clipboard items? Does it not overwrite itself every time?

Comment: @findwindow - I wonder why it won't do two text items? I'd think doing one text and one custom takes up more space than two text items? Weird.

Comment: Because microsoft hates you. Edit: perhaps microsoft can't figure out how to set a delimiter that determines one comment from another lol

Comment: You'd have to store each copy action to an array/dictionary then retrieve it later XD

Comment: @findwindow well that sucks then. It is unbelievable this can't be done.

Comment: Microsoft hates me too.

Comment: @BruceWayne think of the clipboard as an object with properties and methods. A `Range` object can't have 2 `.Address` properties - in a similar way the clipboard can't have two `string` items. It's just the way it's designed.

Comment: Looks like an older implementation, but "benf" created a DLL that is an API to the Office clipboard and can be used from Excel VBA. (go look [here](http://www.benf.org/excel/officeclip/) ). I downloaded the source, but don't have VS in order to build it. This may be closer to a solution, but the Office API itself may have changed since this was written.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there are two clipboards: the Windows clipboard and the Office clipboard.

The Office clipboard can hold up to 24 items (all can be the same type), whereas the Windows clipboard can only hold one item of each type.

- Copying to the Windows clipboard is as easy as highlighting then
  typing Ctrl-C.
- Copying to the Office clipboard is as easy as
  highlighting then typing Ctrl-CC. The Office clipboard is only active
  if there is at least one Office application open and active at the
  time.

In VBA, using the MSForms.DataObject only gets you access to the Windows clipboard, so there is only a single text item available. After a variety of searches, I'm not able to find out how to open/control/copy/paste using the Office clipboard from VBA.

Having said all that, there is likely little reason to use any clipboard when writing and running a VBA macro. You can (temporarily) store those values in unused cells on a worksheet, in a public variable, in a public object, or even a private variable (probably with publically accessible properties). All of those methods serve exactly the same purpose as storing data in the clipboard.

In skimming around the interwebz on this topic, I ran across several references to using the clipboard to copy data between different workbooks, or between Office apps like Excel-to-Word. You still don't need the clipboard for this, as VBA can open the remote/external application/workbook/document and copy/paste the data directly.