# Collecting more than one data from Clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I manually copy 4 or 5 pieces of text from an email body to clipboard.
Then I want a procedure that assigns each one of these piece of text to a string variable separated by semicolons. 
The “codes” below do not work. I write them just to helping explain what I want.
I will appreciate any help.

```
Sub ColectClipboardItems()

    Dim strClip As String

    strClip = vbNullString

    For Each Item In Clipboard.Items

        strClip = strClip & ";" & Item

    Next Item

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's true, but the following link indicates that currently Excel can only handle information from the Windows clipboard, which only stores one value at a time:

[Access The Nth Item of Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463817/access-the-nth-item-of-clipboard)

However, you could try to create the following:

- Two step manual process:

  - A macro in Outlook that stores your data in the Windows clipboard (concatenated). Instead of Ctrl + C you would click a button in your Outlook ribbon.
  - A macro in Excel that retrieves such data from it.

    - I think this is prone to human errors.
- Or a one step process:

  - A macro in Outlook that stores all your data & by itself calls another macro in Excel to save it there.

    - This depends on your e-mail having a consistent structure, though.

Comment: Unfortunately the data to be collected in the email is located in aleatoires places so it is not possible automated the colect process of these data.